# About density of some subsets of infinitely differentiable functions in $C[0,1]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $x_1,...,x_m$ be fixed numbers from $[0,1]$ and let $k_1,..., k_m$ be fixed natural numbers ($\geq 1$).
Is the set
$$\{f\in C^\infty[0,1]: f^{(k_1)}(x_1)=0,...,f^{(k_m)}(x_m)=0 \}$$a dense subset of the Banach space $C[0,1])$, with the supremum norm?

Comment: Try to show: even the polynomials in your set are dense in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Your space is clearly  a subalgebra of $C[0,1]$. The Stone-Wierstrss theorem gives necessary and sufficient  conditions for a subalgebra $A\subset C([0,1])$ to be dense in $C([0,1])$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: It's not an algebra.  Taking $[-1,1]$ instead for convenience, let $m=1$, $k_1 = 2$, and $x_1 = 0$.  Then $f(x) = x$ is in the set but $f^2$ isn't.

Comment: Take any polynomial approximant, you can certainly perturb it near $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ so that the approximant is locally constant near those points. Then just do some book-keeping of $\epsilon$'s you are done.

Comment: For $m=1$ the result is true. Denote by $P$ the  subspace of $C([0,1])$ consisting of polynomials. because the linear functional $C([0,1])$. The linear functional $P\ni p\mapsto p^{(k_1}(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ is not continuous and thus its kernel is dense  in $P$, thus in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: In fact it is sufficient to approximate uniformly the identity function $\iota(x)=x$ by a smooth function $\iota_\epsilon$ which is locally constant at the $x_j$'s, say $|x-\iota_\epsilon(x)|\le\epsilon$. Then for any smooth $P$, with modulus of continuity $\omega$, the function $P\circ\iota_\epsilon$ is locally constant at the $x_j$'s and $\|P-P\circ\iota_\epsilon\|_\infty\le\omega(\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. We prove by induction on $m$.  Denote by $P$ the subspace of $C([0,1])$  consisting of the restrictions to $[0,1]$ of the smooth functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.    Assume first that $x_1,\dotsc, x_m$ are pairwise distinct. Set

$$ P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_k}:=\big\{ p\in P;\;\;p^{(k_i)}(x_i)=0,\;i=1,\dotsc, m\big\}. $$

Then

$$ P\supset P_{x_1},\supset \cdots \supset P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_m}. $$

Let us show  that $P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_m}$ is dense in $P$. The case $m=1$ is dealt with as in my comment.

Let us now prove that $P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_m}$ is dense in $P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_{m-1}}$, thus, inductively, in $P$.

Define the linear functional $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$

$$ L: P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_{m-1}}\to \bR,\;\;L(p)= p^{(k_m)}(x_m). $$

The linear functional $L$ is not continuous  thus its kernel $\ker L=P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_m}$ is dense  in $P_{x_1,\dotsc, x_{m-1}}$.

To see that $L$ is not continuous pick a smooth function $f$ with compact support contained in a neighborhood of $x_m$ disjoint form $x_1,\dotsc, x_{m-1}$   and such that $f^{(k_m)}(x_m)=1$.  Define

$$f_n(x)= n^{-1/2}f\big( x_m+ n(x-x_m)\big).$$

Then the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero but $$f_n^{(k_m)}(x_m)=n^{k_m-1/2}\to\infty.$$

Suppose now that $x_1,\dotsc, x_m$ are not necessarily distinct. For simplicity assume  that $x_1=\cdots=x_m$ and $k_1<\cdots <k_m$.  Then  define

$$ P_{k_1,\dotsc, k_m}:=\big\{ p\in P;\;\;p^{(k_i)}(x_1=0,\;\;i=1,\dotsc, m\big\}. $$
Arguing as above one sees  that $P_{k_1,\dotsc, k_i}$ is dense in $P_{k_1,\dotsc, k_{i-1}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is dense.

Given $f \in C([0,1])$ and $\epsilon > 0$, it is easy to find a continuous function $g$ which is constant on some $\delta$-neighborhood of each $x_i$ and has $\|f-g\| < \epsilon$.  (For instance, Now extend $g$ continuously to all of $\mathbb{R}$, say by making it constant on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[1,\infty)$.  Let $\phi$ be a $C^\infty$ bump function with $\int \phi = 1$ and compactly supported inside $(-\delta, \delta)$.  Then the convolution $h = g \ast \phi$ is also constant on some neighborhood of each $x_i$, so $h^{(k)}(x_i) = 0$ for all $k \ge 1$, and $h \in C^\infty$, so $h$ is in your set.  By choosing the support of $\phi$ as small as needed and using the uniform continuity of $g$, we can get $\|g-h\| < \epsilon$.